# Quick question on orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis

I was wondering if its true for some vector $y \in H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space, that $\langle y, x \rangle = 0, \forall x \in H$ is enough to say $y = 0$.

I want to think this is true as $H$ is trivially topologically closed in itself, so we should be able to decompose $H = H \oplus H^\perp$, but this has that $H^\perp = \{0\}$. Is this sufficient reasoning? I appreciate the help.

Comment: If $\langle y, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in H$, then in particular its true for $x = y$. $0 = \langle y, y \rangle = \|y\|^2$ so $y = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Short, elegant, nice. Thank you!